# Ng2-smart-table doesn't display date time values in IE

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

i am using ng2-smart-table in my angular 7 application,
I have used owl-datetime picker in the table. the values are getting added in the db.

i am getting the values from back end in an array which is getting populated in the table.

but the datetime value is not getting displayed in the box, it is giving me
 "**InvalidPipeArgument : 'Unable to convert "2019-12-24 13:00:00**" into a date' for pipe DatePipe'.

I can't share any code as this'll is my office based application...

any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use moment like this

```js
public date : string = '2019-12-24 13:00:00';
public newDate;

this.newDate =  moment(this.date).format('MMM Do YYYY');
```

than binding this.newDate

```html
<h2> {{newDate}}</h2>
```